# Custom React hook in TypeScript - has no call signatures

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this custom hook to call the API

```
import { useState, useCallback } from 'react';

interface OptionsShape {
  method: 'GET' | 'POST';
}

interface InitStateShape {
  data: any;
  success: boolean;
  loading: boolean;
  error: Error | null;
}

const useAPI = (initialData = null) => {
  const initialState: InitStateShape = {
    data: initialData,
    success: false,
    loading: false,
    error: null,
  };

  const [response, setResponse] = useState(initialState);

  const callAPI = async (URL: string, options: OptionsShape) => {
    setResponse({ ...response, success: false, loading: true });

    try {
      const response = await fetch(URL, options);
      if (response.status < 200 || response.status >= 300)
        throw new Error('Failed to fetch');
      const json = await response.json();
      setResponse({
        data: json,
        success: true,
        loading: false,
        error: null,
      });
    } catch (e) {
      setResponse({
        data: initialData,
        success: false,
        loading: false,
        error: e.message,
      });
    }
  };

  return [response, useCallback(callAPI, [])];
};

export { useAPI };
```

I'm calling it with

```
import { useAPI } from '../hooks/useAPI';
...
const [response, callAPI] = useAPI();
...
callAPI('https://api.mysite.com/test', { method: 'GET' });
```

The error I get on callAPI is:

```
This expression is not callable.
  Not all constituents of type '{ data: null; success: boolean; loading: boolean; error: null; } | ((URL: string, options: OptionsShape) => Promise<void>)' are callable.
    Type '{ data: null; success: boolean; loading: boolean; error: null; }' has no call signatures.ts(2349)
```

Comment: This has to do with the difference between Tuples and Arrays in Typescript. If you specify the type of the return value, the error is gone. The "as const" (answer below) also works, but smells a bit like a workaround.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The return value is inferred as an array and not as a tuple. You can change that by adding `as const`:

```
 return [response, useCallback(callAPI, [])] as const;
```